# how to identify memory leak Increase in memory private bytes not managed heap

Tags: c#, memory, memory-leaks, ibm-mq

I have an .NET core api which connects to IBMMQ, RabbitMQ & MongoDB. And we have custom component which will run dependency health check every 15secs once by conecting to all of its dependencies so that our core api healthcheck can be computed based on dependency available weightage.

Consider IBMMQ service dependency, for which we use amqmdnetstd[] library to connect with IBMMQ

[image]

below is the code we use to run the healthcheck for 15secs once
[image]

Our api is running in PCF environment, even when we run our api in local I could see diagnostic tool, Performance profiler[Memory usage & object allocation tool] is displaying steady increase in memory over 10 mins run and keeps increasing.

[image]

1. Object allocation tool show increase in allocations after GC it reduce all the way and it again starts growing.
2. Memory tool shows that private memory is increasing over time and as part of the service dependency check happening every 15 secs once  uses IBMMQ  dependency check which creates type related to IBMMQ [IBM.WMQ.ManagedTracePoint, etc] which we haven't directly referenced in our code by those types are using more memory and is not getting released.

Questions:

1. Object allocation tool: sub of allocations bytes[show just my code + show native code] is only coming around 5 MB where as private bytes is growing more than 160MB. Does that means the unmanaged codes referenced by the libraries we use doesn't manage those unmanaged object deallocations? How do I check the split of of private bytes160 MB like [Managed objects, native code, unmanaged objects ,etc]
2. The above question applies to memory tool as well where Private bytes goea above 160MB and managed heap shows only 5MB though I select show my code and show native code.
3. Am I doing anything incorrect while trying to connect IBMMQ using amqmdnetstd library in my .NET core api?
4. If we see any types which are not reclaimed[like IBM related types though we use using block while creating IBMMQ related objects in our api impln] by our service dependency driver libraries? Is there a way we can handle in our api to relaim those memory?

Memory profiling using diagnostics and performance profiler

[With testQueueManager.Disconnect() & queue.Close() and false](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uk0fb.png)

Comment: Have you omitted to show us the code that closes the MQ queue or are you not closing it again when you are done with the check?

Comment: @MoragHughson is spot on. To add to her comment, MQ .NET library does NOT close a queue nor disconnect from the queue manager. If your code does not do those things then that is why you have a memory leak.

Comment: I do not have disconnect() or close().Hoping that Dispose() of MQQueueManager is doing disconnect. Let me try adding testQueueManager.Disconnect() and queue.Close() just before exiting the using block.